# Videoview on splash screen

Tags: android, eclipse, android-videoview

I'm making an app that plays a video in a videoview as a splash screen. It doesn't work on the emulator and several real phones, it says "Sorry, this video cannot be played.". I have tried a lot of types of videos (all supported according to http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html), the last I have tried is this: http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/BlackBerry.3gp. I also searched for solution on the internet. But none of them was working.
Where is the mistake?
My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView_circle"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView_loading"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/videoView_circle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView_circle);
    //MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    // mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    //videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);

    videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://com.tamaskoos.tbbt/raw/blackberry");

    videoView.start();  
}


}
```

And my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.koostamas.tbbt"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.koostamas.tbbt.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.koostamas.tbbt.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

And also here is my logcat:

```
03-18 18:14:35.659: D/MediaPlayer(348): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server        side
03-18 18:14:35.748: E/MediaPlayer(348): error (1, -2147483648)
03-18 18:14:35.860: E/MediaPlayer(348): Error (1,-2147483648)
03-18 18:14:35.860: D/VideoView(348): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

I'm messing with this for a really long time. I would be very happy if someone could help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)`"Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side"` this message refers that can´t open the file because codecs are not supported or the file doesn´t exist, your file inside the /raw folder must be named "`blackberry.3gp`"

2) the package of your app is `com.koostamas.tbbt`, not  `com.tamaskoos.tbbt` that you have defined here:

```
 videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://com.tamaskoos.tbbt/raw/blackberry");
```

change the package name to load the video resource:

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView_circle);
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.koostamas.tbbt/" + R.raw.blackberry));
videoView.start();
```

Comment: I read your answer and still took me a while to actually spot the wrong package name! Nice!