# Android: Sound File Not Found

Tags: android, file, audio, media-player

I know there are lots of similar problems to mine, but for some reason the answers to those questions don't seem to work. I am using android and have a sound file named 'backgroundbeat.wav' and I'm trying to import it but instead I get the error:

```
  "failed to open file 'res\raw\backgroundbeat.wav'. (No such file in directory)"
```

Here is the code where I use the media player:

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try{
            mp.setDataSource("res/raw/backgroundbeat.wav");
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your app package name to define the correct path :

```
mp.setDataSource("android.resource://<YOURPACKAGE_NAME>/raw/backgroundbeat");
```

example:

```
 mp.setDataSource("android.resource://com.jorgesys.myapp/raw/backgroundbeat");
```

or other way to load a media file from `/raw` folder, if you are inside an activity you could use:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.backgroundbeat);
```

or You can use a VideoView to play your file
**[Videoview on splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486460/videoview-on-splash-screen/22487798#22487798)**

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help. While I was still having issues with the first part of your example, I took your advice and moved all of the MediPlayer code from my view class to my activity class and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not much experienced in this but you can try to use `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd)` instead of `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String path)`. See [MediaPlayer setDataSource, better to use path or FileDescriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625680/mediaplayer-setdatasource-better-to-use-path-or-filedescriptor) . Apparently if you call `prepare()` while using string as a parameter to `setDataSource`, it is causing some issues as per the answers.

You may try something like:

```
// Use the proper context instead of *context* variable
InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.backgroundbeat);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(in.getFD())
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that issue to me, I really appreciate it. I was still having some trouble with the code though, so I moved everything into an activity class instead of in a view class and things went a lot better.